# Using configuration for an OSGi bundle

Tags: java, osgi, apache-karaf, karaf

I'm making an OSGi bundle and have some configurable parameters that it needs.  I followed the [instructions for karaf](https://karaf.apache.org/manual/latest/#_configuration_3) and the configuration values show up in webconsole.  But how can they be used in Java?

I tried `context.getProperty("prop1")` in the Actuator, `System.getProperty("prop1")`, and even [registering a ManagedService](https://www.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/en/SSEQTP_liberty/com.ibm.websphere.wlp.doc/ae/twlp_receive_config_data_managedservice.html).  The property is always coming back as null.  This should be really easy.  What am I missing?

Comment: For the ManagedService: Did you check that the service PID (also displayed in webconsole) matches the configuration PID?

Answer (score 0):

Put the configuration properties to `etc/system.properties` and `System.getProperty()` should work.

The same can be achieved with property placeholders (see [40482233](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40482233/osgi-property-placeholder)) and `ConfigurationAdmin` (see [30474886](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30474886/how-to-load-external-properties-file-through-osgi-blueprint-property-placeholder)).

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at this tutorial: http://liquid-reality.de/display/liquid/2011/09/23/Karaf+Tutorial+Part+2+-+Using+the+Configuration+Admin+Service

It shows how to work with ConfigAdmin properties both programmatically and using blueprints.

Answer (score 0):

The cause was a race-condition with the `updated()` method of `ManagedService`.  It gets executed when calling `registerService()`, BUT `configRef` does NOT return `properties` that have the configuration info.  Also, the dictionary passed to `registerService()` is not populated with existing configuration values.

Here's some sample groovy code to explain better.  (Note: `properties` is a reserved word in groovy..maybe that is causing some issues here):

```
class Activator implements BundleActivator, ManagedService{
private ServiceRegistration<ManagedService> configRef
private Dictionary<String,?> configuration

@Override
void start(BundleContext context) throws Exception {
    Dictionary d=new Hashtable()
    d.put(Constants.SERVICE_PID,myPID)
    configRef=context.registerService(ManagedService,this,d)

    log.debug("context.getProperty():"+context.getProperty("prop1"))
    log.debug("System.getProperty():"+System.getProperty("prop1"))
    log.debug("configRef.properties.get():"+configRef.properties.get("prop1"))
    log.debug("d.get():"+d.get("prop1"))
    log.debug("configuration.get():"+configuration.get("prop1"))
 }

...

@Override
void updated(Dictionary<String, ?> properties) throws ConfigurationException {
    log.warn("properties.get() on updated():"+properties.get("prop1"))
    configuration=properties
}
```

This produces the following output:

```
[WARN ] [..Activator] - properties.get() on updated():hello
[DEBUG] [..Activator] - context.getProperty():null
[DEBUG] [..Activator] - System.getProperty():null
[DEBUG] [..Activator] - configRef.properties.get():null
[DEBUG] [..Activator] - d.get():null
[DEBUG] [..Activator] - configuration.get():hello
```

Changing the `updated()` method to populate a class-level Dictionary field seems to work.  In practice, using `configuration` for `d` in the `start()` method is probably a better idea, but this code shows what's really happening.

Thanks for the help everyone!